# How can I set socks4 proxy for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, socks

i need to set socks version 4 but i have a lot of search but i can't find my answer.
finally i wrote this codes but i get error

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.autodetect = False
prox.socks_proxy = '<ip>:<port>'
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

My Error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: proxy
from invalid argument: Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PROXY = "127.0.0.1:9150"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "socksProxy": PROXY,
    "socksVersion":5

}
```

you can use desired capabilities , you don't have to pass it as you are updating the capabilities for chrome directly

else you can also use

```
PROXY = "127.0.0.1:9150"
caps= webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    "socksProxy": PROXY,
    "socksVersion":5

}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Comment: thanks it's wok only change socksVersion to 4

Comment: It depends on your proxy , If it used version for change it to 4 ese 5

Comment: For=four ,.   Typo